# Append an item to an existing list

Tags: c#

I am working with a link list. I have set my constructor to take an array named `ax` with a set of already defined items. I also decided to have an input box which through a `BtnAddTree_Click` appends the new item to the list `ax`. But instead of appending to the list `ax` it creates a whole new separate list. How can I append items to the array list `ax` through my `AddTree` function?

```
            public ListForTrees(IEnumerable<fruit_trees> trees)
            {
                foreach (fruit_trees t in trees)
                {
                    this.AddTree(t);
                }
            }



            public void AddTree(fruit_trees new_tree)
            {
                fruit_trees current = first_tree;

                if (count == 0)
                {
                    first_tree = new_tree;
                    last_tree = new_tree;
                    count = 1;
                }

                else if (count != 0)
                {
                    if (new_tree.tree_price <= first_tree.tree_price)
                    {
                        new_tree.next_tree = first_tree;
                        first_tree = new_tree;
                    }
                    else if (new_tree.tree_price >= last_tree.tree_price)
                    {
                        last_tree.next_tree = new_tree;
                        last_tree = new_tree;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (new_tree.tree_price > current.next_tree.tree_price)
                        {
                            current = current.next_tree;
                        }
                        new_tree.next_tree = current.next_tree;
                        current.next_tree = new_tree;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }

        ListForTrees mainlist = new ListForTrees();

        private void BtnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fruit_trees[] ax = {   new fruit_trees("cherry", 48, 12.95, 3),
                                             new fruit_trees("pine", 36, 9.95, 8),
                                             new fruit_trees("oak", 60, 14.95, 2),
                                             new fruit_trees("peach", 54, 19.95, 3),
                                             new fruit_trees("pear", 36, 11.85, 2),
                                             new fruit_trees("apple", 62, 13.45, 5)
                                         };

            mainlist = new ListForTrees(ax);
            fruit_trees current = mainlist.first_tree;
            while (current != null)
            {                   
                current = current.next_tree;             
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pease consider making samples much smaller. It is very hard to see what you problem is... If you want your code to be reviewed and commented on - there is codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why do you need to attach all class code? Is not enough method BtnAddTree_Click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be creating a new separate list. I tested out the following code with yours:

```
public class TreeTester
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var list = new ListForTrees(
        new[] { new fruit_trees("tree10",10,10,10), new fruit_trees("tree2",2,2,2) });

    list.AddTree( new fruit_trees("tree3",3,3,3) );     // middle
    list.AddTree( new fruit_trees("tree1",1,1,1) );     // first
    list.AddTree( new fruit_trees("tree50",50,50,50) ); // last
    list.AddTree( new fruit_trees("tree5",5,5,5) );     // middle
    Console.Write(list);
  }
}
```

And got the following output, which seems correct.

```
tree1 1 1 1
tree2 2 2 2
tree3 3 3 3
tree5 5 5 5
tree10 10 10 10
tree50 50 50 50
```

What is the expected behavior, if this is not correct? Clearly these items *are* all being added to the original list, since they're present when I iterate through the list.

By the way, I also added the following `ToString` function to your `ListForTrees` class; it makes debugging easier.

```
public override string ToString()
{
  string s = "";
  for (var tree=first_tree; tree!=null; tree = tree.next_tree)
    s += tree + "\n";
  return s;
}
```

---

*Edit*: I must comment that you may find it helpful to cleanup your code a bit in trying to understand where it is going wrong. For example, your `ListForTrees(fruit_trees new_tree)` constructor does the same exact thing as calling `Add(new_tree)` would. Also, think about three cases you have in Add, under `else if (count != 0)` -- perhaps there's a way they could elegantly combined into one general while loop? It makes it easier to analyze, and (potentially) less error-prone.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It is displaying it as one whole list with new items inserted. I think what confused me was that it is appending item to the beginning of the list no the end. how can i fix that?

Comment: Check the else statement below `else if (count != 0)`... It's inserting it in *sorted* order! If you want to always add it to the end of the list, you'll always want to use the second case: `last_tree.next_tree = new_tree; last_tree = new_tree;`

Comment: You helped me greatly last time.  I have different question regarding link list and displaying position of itme. Please check: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863114/show-position-of-item-in-a-link-list)